# Powershell Copy-Item remote machine copying to wrong location

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I am on server A (dev box) creating a remote Powershell session to server B (IIS server). The script copies from server C (build machine) to server B.

I got passed (I think) the multi-hop credential issue EXCEPT the copy is copying to the wrong location on server B.

It is supposed to copy to d:\wwwroot\HelloWorld but instead is copying to c:\users\me\Documents\HelloWorld.

All servers are Win2012r2 and on a domain using powershell v3.

run on server B:

```
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{CredSSP="true"}'
```

run on server A:

```
winrm set winrm/config/client/auth '@{CredSSP="true"}'
```

And here is my script:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "mypassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("mydomain\me", $password)
$sesh = new-pssession -computername "ServerB" -credential $cred -Authentication CredSSP

$sitePath = "D:\wwwroot\HelloWorld"
Invoke-Command -Session $sesh -ScriptBlock { 
    Copy-Item -path "\\ServerC\Builds\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.1\_PublishedWebsites\HelloWorld" -Destination $sitePath -Recurse -Force
}
```

Why isn't it listening to my destination?

Comment: `help about_Remote_Variables`

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149005.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [remote variable documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149005.aspx). Your `$Sitepath` is defined locally and is not defined in the remote script block.

So either use the syntax that brings in a local variable:

```
$sitePath = "D:\wwwroot\HelloWorld"
Invoke-Command -Session $sesh -ScriptBlock { 
    Copy-Item -path "\\ServerC\Builds\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.1\_PublishedWebsites\HelloWorld" 
              -destination $Using:sitePath -Recurse -Force
}
```

Or define it in the Script Block:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $sesh -ScriptBlock { 
    $sitePath = "D:\wwwroot\HelloWorld"
    Copy-Item -path "\\ServerC\Builds\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.1\_PublishedWebsites\HelloWorld" -Destination $sitePath -Recurse -Force
}
```

Comment: not a complete answer.... What if $sitePath is a parameter to the script? However, I am reading the documentation for the complete answer.

Comment: I'm that case you need to bring it in using the first syntax.

Comment: Sorry, missed the first syntax. Works perfect!